# Wordpress - List of posts by category after clicking category link

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

On my wordpress site I have a page that lists all categories and sub categories using the following code.

```
<ul>
<?php 
$parents = get_categories(array('parent' => 0, 'exclude' => '1,7','hide_empty' => 0));
if(!empty($parents)){
    foreach($parents as $parent){
        ?>
        <li>
            <div class="catImg">
                <span><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($parent->term_id); ?>" /></span>
            </div>
            <h2><?php echo $parent->name; ?></h2>
            <ul class="models">
                <?php wp_list_categories(array('hierarchical' => false, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'title_li' => __( '' ), 'show_option_none'   => __( '' ), 'child_of' => $parent->term_id)); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
} else { 
    ?>
    <li>No Categories</li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The code above generates multiple blocks like the photo below. In the photo, 'Team Losi Racing' is the parent category, '8ight 3.0' and '8ight EU' are subcategories of Team Losi Racing.

[image]

When I click on the sub categories within the ul.models list I would like to be taken to a page that lists all posts within that category.

As I'm new to wordpress and this is my first theme, I was wondering if someone could possibly point me in the right direction to achieving the above result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific. What you exactly want to do?

Comment: Im after clicking the sub categories link on the categories page, I would like to view a list of all posts within that subcategory.

Comment: K. I have two doubts. 1.On the click it will load another page? 2.show the posts link or full content?

Comment: 1. At the moment when I click on the subcategories link, it takes me the category.php page which returns 'no categories'. ---- 2. I am just looking to display the post title and link it to a page with the full post content.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER ONE**

As my understanding. You can do like below. Just try this. If you have any query or concern feel free to contact me in any network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

**CODE**

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $parents = get_categories(array('parent' => 0, 'exclude' => '1,7','hide_empty' => 0));
    if(!empty($parents)){
        foreach($parents as $parent){
            ?>
            <li>
                <div class="catImg">
                    <span><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($parent->term_id); ?>" /></span>
                </div>
                <h2><?php echo $parent->name; ?></h2>
                <ul class="models">
                    <?php 
                      $categories = get_categories('child_of'=>$parent->ID); //Pass the Parent category id here
                      foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        echo '<li>'.$category->cat_name.'</li>';//Child cat list
                        //Show links by using css after click above sub-cat name
                        ?>
                        <ul class="sub-cat-post-links">
                        <?php
                            $args = array( 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $category->cat_ID );
                            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; 
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php
                      }
                     ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    } else { 
        ?>
        <li>No Categories</li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

**Explanation**

From your code you can get the parent category. Then we can get the child category of that parents. In the child category list we can list down the posts belongs to child and parent. That list will show after you click on the child cat name. You have to do some css also on that. When we click on the posts name/title. It will take us to the post.`single.php`

Thanks. This is so quick. Sorry for my bad english

**Brief Look**

In my answer, Regarding your que image. `Team Losi Racing` and `XRAY` is parent category names. `8ight 3.0` and `8ight EU` is child category names. When you click on child cat names. It will show the belongs posts below the `child category name`. like drop down. After you click on the post link. It will take you to the post contents.

As per our discuss please see below second answer. i don't want to delete the first answer. It also help to someone.

**ANSWER TWO**

here is the code. You can do like below. Just try this. If you have any query or concern feel free to contact me in any network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $parents = get_categories(array('parent' => 0, 'exclude' => '1,7','hide_empty' => 0));
    if(!empty($parents)){
        foreach($parents as $parent){
            ?>
            <li>
                <div class="catImg">
                    <span><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($parent->term_id); ?>" /></span>
                </div>
                <h2><?php echo $parent->name; ?></h2>
                <ul class="models">
                    <?php 
                      $categories = get_categories('child_of'=>$parent->ID); //Pass the Parent category id here
                      foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        echo '<li>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </li> ';
                      }
                     ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    } else { 
        ?>
        <li>No Categories</li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

**Brief Look**

On above one. We are taking that child categories from parents cats. After that, we are display the link to that sub category. When click on the link it will take us to the category post list `archive.php` page. In there you can style you like.

Many Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry but there seems to be a slight miss-understanding. When I click on the sub categories, I would like to be taken to a new page listing all the posts within the category that I clicked. Is this possible please?

So for example, you have the category list page, then when you click on a sub category, you are taken to a post list page, that lists all posts within the category you clicked.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have lot of ways to do it. Easy way **Option1**.You can pass the sub-cat-id to the category page and then you can get the list of posts by that sub-cat-id. **Option 2**.You can create a single shortcode function in `function.php` and the you have to create a `template` after that you have to create pages using that page template for each sub-cat

Comment: Okay cool, so Option 1. how would I go about passing the subcatid to the category page and display the posts? Thank you

Comment: K. I will add another answer for that. Your Welcome

Comment: @OliverEvans Please see second answer